# Regex based rules clause does not work in GitLab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want my Gitlab CI job to **not** run when the commit message starts with a particular string: `[maven-scm]`

So, I have the below configuration in my *.gitlab-ci.yaml* file:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: all
    paths:
      - ./.m2/repository
  script:
    - mvn clean checkstyle:check test spotbugs:check
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^\[maven-scm\] .*$/'
```

My commit message is: `[maven-scm] I hope the test job does not run`

But the test job still runs to my frustration. I went over the GitLab documentation for [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) but could not find the reason why the job still runs. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

**Update:**

I tried the only/except clause instead of the rules. I modified the yaml file to below:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: all
    paths:
      - ./.m2/repository
  script:
    - mvn clean checkstyle:check test spotbugs:check
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[maven-scm\] .*$/
```

The job still runs when the commit message starts with `[maven-scm]`.

Comment: Alright I finally figured it out. The issue was with the regex, not the `rules` clause. See answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a tricky problem, because the issue was not with the `rules` section. The problem is actually the regex. You only need to specify the desired pattern at the start of the commit message, i.e. don't need the following wildcard. The following works and has been tested:

```yaml
test-rules:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^\[maven-scm\] /'
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE"
```

This has been tested with the following commit messages:

- `This commit message will run the job`
- `This commit message [maven-scm] will run the job`
- `[maven-scm] This commit message will NOT run the job`

FYI GitLab documentation specifies that `rules` is preferred over `only/except`, so best to stick with `rules: if`. See [onlyexcept-basic](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyexcept-basic).

Comment: Did you read the first line of the question fully? My requirement is that the job should **not** run if the commit message starts with [maven-scm]. Your suggestion looks like it does the exact opposite - it runs the job only if the commit message starts with [maven-scm].

Comment: Sorry, read too fast. Updated answer to match your requirements.

Comment: Great! This seems to work. But again, I believe, the rules should say '!~' instead of '=~' for my requirement. Can you correct that?

Comment: Good catch! If all is good now, please upvote/select as correct answer. Sorry for all the back-and-forth.

Comment: Done. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it. Thank you.